# How to design this relationship between classes?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, uml, decorator

I recently had an object/class design question. The problem was this:

> "You have a University and it has employees, which can be either Student or  Teacher."

They asked me to design only the relationship of the employees so I made a simple inheritance diagram

Then he asked me what happens if Student can be a Teacher, it can't inherit from Employee and Teacher. I couldn't answer so he designed a solution with a Role class.

Another solution could've been using the Decorator Pattern?

My 1st solution :

[image]

His solution to the problem of multiple inheritances

[image]

Alternative solution?

[image]

What do you think of these approaches?

Thanks

Edit: I found a video on YouTube where they describe and solve this problem, they used the same Role-based solution using composition.
https://youtu.be/dYUZiJEy0JE?t=1252

Comment: Maybe better site for your question would be https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, but you would probably need to provide also *code* for each diagram you created.

Comment: It is a weak question: "the employee can be *either* a Student *or* a Teacher". His solution allows for employees that do not have any role unless the invariant of an employee having to be either one of the two roles is enforced by the creator of the "employee" object. With University out of the picture, he actually makes yours the better solution; that is, a disjoint specialisation from Employee to Student or Teacher. [This question is similar](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/262800/how-to-orm-non-disjoint-specializations) .

Comment: If I was interviewing and you dropped a design pattern in the answer, I would not look at this well. Always start from first principles when you want to convince people of your knowledge, and design patterns are ready-made answers that should be avoided unless asked explicitly for them.

Comment: My correct solution would be [this](https://ideone.com/V34bZZ) because the scope of the question allows for it. A student or a teacher is just a person. If the use-case is to maintain registries of both, this solution works just fine by adding each teacher or student to the correct "buckets" after instantiation. It also shows that each person object is the same regardless of which buckets they are added to.

Comment: @RWRkeSBZ Your first comment is actually the right answer. You should post it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a weak question: "the employee can be *either* a Student *or* a Teacher". His solution allows for employees that do not have any role unless the invariant of an employee having to be either one of the two roles is enforced by the creator of the "employee" object. With University out of the picture, he actually makes yours the better solution; that is, a disjoint specialisation from Employee to Student or Teacher. [This question is similar](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/262800/how-to-orm-non-disjoint-specializations).

Comment: "employee _can be_ either a Student or a Teacher"
Is this different from "employee _is_ either a Student or a Teacher" ?
Maybe "_can be_" implies that an employee is not always either a Student or a Teacher.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a typical situation that can be solved using the **Party-PartyRole** pattern.

Using a generalization from **Student/Teacher** to Employee will get you in trouble at some time because now you can't model **Students** who aren't **Employees**.

[image]

This pattern works for all kinds of roles parties can partake in.

You will have to add an additional constraint on the Employee class however to indicate that an Employee should be either a Teacher or a Student (apparently this university has no administrative, cleaning, maintenance, .... staff)

**Note:** This might not be the answer your teacher is looking for, but it is a usable way to model these things in the *real world*.